# 1 doesn't equal 1? Matrix entry comparison in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, floating-point, equality

I'm trying to test an inversion of a matrix by multiplying it to get 1. I check if it equals 1, and if not, then print a message and the value of the matrix entry.

The problem is that the printed matrix entry *is* 1. I even use a rounding function I know works to make sure there's nothing wrong with floating point inaccuracies.

Here's my code:

```matlab
 function [D1,f]=stiff(D,y)
 n = size(D,2);
 D1 = inv(D);
 f = D1 * y;
 for i = 1:n
        for j = 1:n
            if j == i % checking for diagonal entry
                yTempVar = D * D1 (1:n, i);
                if truncateFunction (yTempVar(j), 1) ~= 1
                    fprintf ("something's wrong")
                    truncateFunction (yTempVar(j), 1)
                 return
             end
         end
     end
 end

function B=truncateFunction(A,pow)
A(abs(A)<10^-pow)=0;
B=A;
```

The corresponding output is this:

```
something's wrong
ans = 1.0000
```

I've also tried it without the rounding function, and I've tried it against 1.0000

Here's what I have in my live script to test with

```py
D=rand(4)*0.1;
y=randi([10 20], 4,1);
stiff(D,y)
```

Comment: Can you give us a complete example that we can run? I.E. give us a value for `D`,`n`, and a definition of `truncateFunction` such that you don't get the expected result?

Comment: @MarkSnyder Sorry about that. I have to be discrete with my code as it's for a project. I edited it to have a working test case

Comment: I still can't run your code (no definition of `truncateFunction`), but regardless, are you really, **really** sure that `truncateFunction` is actually reliable? Try using something like `if abs(yTempVar(j) - 1) > .000001` or some other small number and see if that works instead.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to include that! Once again, sorry. Interestingly enough, that seemed to work great!

Here's the algorithm used in truncateFunction():
`function B=truncateFunction(A,pow)`
`A(abs(A)<10^-pow)=0;`
`B=A;`
It's a little hard to dissect, but I was told to trust it. Oh well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`truncateFunction` doesn't do what you think it does. It only rounds values below the given power of ten down to zero - it doesn't round to the nearest integer at all, unless that integer is zero.

In general, it's better with floating point issues (which this is) to check that values are within a small value rather than being equal.

```
epsilon = .00001
if abs(yTempVar(j)-1) > epsilon
    fprintf ("something's wrong")
    truncateFunction (yTempVar(j), 1)
    return
```